# Numpy concatenate simple string with the values of a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, concatenation, numpy-ndarray

I want to concatenate a simple string with the values of a numpy array.

I have create a new numpy array with np.arrange to get a incremental list of number [0, 1, 2].
But I am not able to concatenate each number with a string "User".

I tried to concatenate with the numpy function concatenate and defchararray without success. It seems like the concatenate function only concatenate two numpy arrays but not concatenate a string and an array.

Here is the code:

```
Anon_id = np.arange(10)

print np.core.defchararray.add('User',Anon_id)
print np.concatenate('User',Anon_id)
```

Can you help me figure out a solution, please ?

Best regards.

Comment: does this have to be done a) in python2 and b) in numpy? in python3, that could simply be `users = [f'User{i}' for i in range(10)]`

Comment: The environnement is in python2, I prefer a solution with numpy. jdehesa solution seems better because there are no loop specify in the code. Thanks.

Comment: "no loops visible" is not necessarily better imho (a loop will be running somewhere anyway). Added a `timeit` comparison for reference. Anyways, jdehesa's solution is nice, so +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to convert the integer array to strings:

```
import numpy as np
out = np.core.defchararray.add('User', np.arange(10).astype(str))
print(out)
# ['User0' 'User1' 'User2' 'User3' 'User4' 'User5' 'User6' 'User7' 'User8'
#  'User9']
```

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this:

```
np.array(['User{}'.format(i) for i in range(10)])
```

Answer (score 2):

A little %timeit comparison for reference:

```
%timeit [f'User{i}' for i in range(10)]
2.39 µs ± 106 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit np.core.defchararray.add('User', np.arange(10).astype(str))
23.9 µs ± 1.85 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

and for larger arrays

```
%timeit [f'User{i}' for i in range(1000)]
214 µs ± 8.73 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit np.core.defchararray.add('User', np.arange(1000).astype(str))
1.18 ms ± 15.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Can't check for Python2 right now but native Python3 (3.7.5, 64bit) is hard to beat here! For large array sizes, the performance advantage of native Python roughly converges to x6.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

# create a list
Anon_id = list(map(str, np.arange(10)))

# join User string in a different step
print(np.core.defchararray.add('User', Anon_id))

## ['User0' 'User1' 'User2' 'User3' 'User4' 'User5' 'User6' 'User7' 'User8' 'User9']
```